# Handling read/write udp connection in Go

Tags: go, udp

I need to create UDP connection through which I could write and read packets simultaneously. (using different goroutines and with GOMAXPROCS(n) where n>1) First attempt was something like this:

```
func new_conn(port, chan_buf int) (conn *net.UDPConn, inbound chan Packet, err error) {
    inbound = make(chan Packet, chan_buf)

    conn, err = net.ListenUDP("udp4", &net.UDPAddr{Port: port})
    if err != nil {return}

    go func () {
        for {
            b := make([]byte, UDP_PACKET_SIZE)
            n, addr, err := conn.ReadFromUDP(b)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Error: UDP read error: %v", err)
                continue
            }
            inbound <- Packet{addr, b[:n]}
        }
    }
}
```

So to read packet I used **packet := <- inbound** and to write **conn.WriteTo(data_bytes, remote_addr)**. But [race detector](http://blog.golang.org/race-detector) issues warnings on simultaneous read/write on connection. So I rewrite code to something like this:

```
func new_conn(port, chan_buf int) (inbound, outbound chan Packet, err error) {
    inbound = make(chan Packet, chan_buf)
    outbound = make(chan Packet, chan_buf)

    conn, err = net.ListenUDP("udp4", &net.UDPAddr{Port: port})
    if err != nil {return}

    go func () {
        for {
            select {
            case packet := <- outbound:
                _, err := conn.WriteToUDP(packet.data, packet.addr)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("Error: UDP write error: %v", err)
                    continue
                }
            default:
                b := make([]byte, UDP_PACKET_SIZE)
                n, addr, err := conn.ReadFromUDP(b)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("Error: UDP read error: %v", err)
                    continue
                }
                inbound <- Packet{addr, b[:n]}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code will no more trigger race condition, but have risk of blocking goroutine if there is no inbound packets. Only solution which I see is to call something like **SetReadDeadline(time.Now()+10*time.Millisecond)** before calling ReadFromUDP. This code will probably work, but I don't like it so much. Is there more elegant ways to solve this problem?

**UPD:** Warning message:

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read by goroutine 553:
  net.ipToSockaddr()
      /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/ipsock_posix.go:150 +0x18a
  net.(*UDPAddr).sockaddr()
      /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/udpsock_posix.go:45 +0xd9
  net.(*UDPConn).WriteToUDP()
      /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/udpsock_posix.go:123 +0x4df
  net.(*UDPConn).WriteTo()
      /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/udpsock_posix.go:139 +0x2f6
  <traceback which points on conn.WriteTo call>

Previous write by goroutine 556:
  syscall.anyToSockaddr()
      /usr/local/go/src/pkg/syscall/syscall_linux.go:383 +0x336
  syscall.Recvfrom()
      /usr/local/go/src/pkg/syscall/syscall_unix.go:223 +0x15c
  net.(*netFD).ReadFrom()
      /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/fd_unix.go:227 +0x33c
  net.(*UDPConn).ReadFromUDP()
      /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/udpsock_posix.go:67 +0x164
  <traceback which points on conn.ReadFromUDP call>

Goroutine 553 (running) created at:
  <traceback>

Goroutine 556 (running) created at:
  <traceback>
==================
```

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: It's not an error but warning. If I run first example with --race flag I 'll get warning from race detection. (I will try to recreate this warning and will paste it in the next comment)

Comment: its probably complaining that you are accessing the same variable in two goroutines (its a pointer), but anything implementing Conn can handle multiple goroutines accesing it: "Multiple goroutines may invoke methods on a Conn simultaneously."

Comment: Updated initial post with race warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the trace from the race detector, the detected race appears to be due to the reuse of a `UDPAddr` returned by a read call in a subsequent write.  In particular, the data its `IP` field references.

It's not clear that this is really a problem though, since `syscall.ReadFrom` is allocating a new address structure on every call and doesn't hold on to that structure long term.  You could try copying the address prior to sending it to your outbound goroutine.  For example:

```
newAddr := new(net.UDPAddr)
*newAddr = *addr
newAddr.IP = make(net.IP, len(addr.IP))
copy(newAddr.IP, add.IP)
```

But without knowing more about your program, it is difficult to tell why this is being flagged as a race.  Perhaps it is enough to point you in the right direction though.  I wasn't able to reproduce the race using this test program based on what you've posted: http://play.golang.org/p/suDG6hCYYP

Comment: Seems problem was indeed with UDPAddr. Copying it before calling WriteTo seems solved problem with race warnings. But it pretty strange, because program must act like server, i.e. address is reused from inbound packet, so read is always goes after write. Or can Go race detector issue false positive with very close write-read? Well, anyway it's a good starting point for further improvements. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised too, since the test program I linked at the end of my answer doesn't trigger the race detector.  Perhaps look at how your code differs to the simple example and see if that could explain the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why not start two goroutines, one for writing and one for reading and be full duplex? i.e:

```
func new_conn(port, chan_buf int) (inbound, outbound chan Packet, err error) {
    inbound = make(chan Packet, chan_buf)
    outbound = make(chan Packet, chan_buf)

    conn, err = net.ListenUDP("udp4", &net.UDPAddr{Port: port})
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    go func() {
        for packet := range outbound {
            _, err := conn.WriteToUDP(packet.data, packet.addr)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Error: UDP write error: %v", err)
                continue
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {

        b := make([]byte, UDP_PACKET_SIZE)
        for {

            n, addr, err := conn.ReadFromUDP(b)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Error: UDP read error: %v", err)
                continue
            }
            b2 := make([]byte, UDP_PACKET_SIZE)
            copy(b2, b)
            inbound <- Packet{addr, b2[:n]}
        }
    }()

}
```

Comment: This approach essentially equal to the first one in my post. So it will trigger race condition.

Comment: You don't actually need to have the same `conn` for both, it's UDP, not TCP.

Comment: But if I try to open second connection on the same port I'll get error "bind: address already in use". Reading from one port and writing to another is not a solution, because I need to write and read from the same port.

Comment: It's curious to me that you actually get this error - writing and reading from a UDP socekt should be thread safe. Can you post the exact warning? It might be something you can just ignore.

Comment: Updated initial post with race warning.

Comment: from what I see the warning is related to the chance of writing and reading to the same packet at the same time. We can see this can't happen because you allocate a new buffer per packet. So I think (without seeing your write code in the first example) that this is safe. You can maybe use a static read buffer for all the packets, and copy it to a newly allocated buffer just before writing to the channel.

Comment: Guess about writing to the same packet was pretty close. But as James pointed, problem was due use of pointer to UDPAddr. Thank you anyway.